# Probability function- Random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I need to find a Probability function using

$$
F(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x<0$}\\
\frac{1-a^k}{1-a^{n+1}} & \text{if $k-1 \leq x \leq k, k=1,\dots,n, n>1$}\\
1 & \text{if $x \geq n$}
\end{cases}
$$

Could someone help me with this exercise?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $F(x)$ has the properties of a distribution function as long as $0\lt a\lt 1$.  Define what you are looking for. (Probability function?)

Comment: Yes, Sorry I forgot to write that: 0 < a < 1. I need to find the Probability function of the corresponding cdf.

Comment: My book calls it Probability function. The result is: p(x)= (a^x)/[sum k=1,..,n of (a^k)]   for x=0,..,n

Comment: $\frac{a^k-a^{k+1}}{1-a^{n+1}}=a^k\frac{1-a}{1-a^{n+1}}=\frac{a^k}{\sum_{j=0}^na^j}$, so we agree. (Almost, check lower limit of sum).

Comment: Since there is a jump at x=0, you need to include k=0 in the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a term (probability function) that I am not familiar with.  Do you mean probability density function?  If so, you are dealing with a discrete distribution with $p_k\gt 0$ defined for $x=k,\ 0\le k\le n$.  $p_k=\frac{a^k-a^{k+1}}{1-a^{n+1}}$